# Jax-ws, spring and SpringBeanAutowiringSupport

Tags: java, spring, jax-ws, cxf, autowired

although in my @Webservice class 
I extend  SpringBeanAutowiringSupport, autowiring simply does not work for Spring 2.5,
tomcat6.

nothing is injected.

I tested those beans autowiring in main method, using classpathcontext, everything is injected fine.
But not for jax-ws endpoint.

do you have ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're using this config element:

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

But to enable support for the @Endpoint annotation, you must add this element:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="" />
```

Comment: I was talking about "jaxws:endpoint" xml element. I use component scan, as you mentioned, but with non-empty base-package, ie base-package="pack1,pack2". Still does not work :)

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I have the configuration mention in this answer.  I'm using GlassFish 3.1 and Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

I've found the solution. The problem is that Spring doesn't autowire beans for `@WebService` classes (as found on other forums it might be a current bug).

**The solution**:

Use `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AutowireCapableBeanFactory.class` instead of using `@Autowired` annotation for injecting your beans (e.g. `@Service`, `@Repository` etc).

So:

1. include `@Resource` `WebServiceContext`

   ```
   @Resource
   private WebServiceContext context;
   ```
2. use it for getting your bean

   ```
   MyDAO myDAO = null;
   ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) context
       .getMessageContext().get("javax.xml.ws.servlet.context");
   WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils
       .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
   myDAO = (MyDAO) webApplicationContext
       .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().getBean("myDAO");
   ```

   `MyDAO` class can be as follows:

   ```
   @Service
   @Qualifier("myDAO")    
   @Transactional
   public class MyDAO {
       private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

       @Required
       @Autowired
       public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
           this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
       }

       public MyInfo getMyInfo(Long id){
           return this.hibernateTemplate.get(MyInfo.class, id);
       }

       //...
   }
   ```
3. after this you can use `myDAO` object in the `@WebMethod` method.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it's the same case as everyone else. It worked for me by changing the order of the listeners in web.xml. Putting the ContextLoaderListener before WSServletContextListener resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you used some reference implementation, like Metro, Axis2, apache-cxf for easy configuration of such endpoint on web service.