# Spring REST services and JAX WS services in same context

Tags: spring, jax-ws, jax-rs

I have a spring webapp with a DispatcherServlet and some REST webservices. This works fine.

When adding some JAX WS endpoints (`@WebService`) and exporting using `SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter` it seems like this takes over the entire namespace of the servlet. I can no longer access static resources or the REST services.

I tried setting the baseAddress property to `http://example.com:8080/soap/` but it still gives 404's for /*.

Is there anything I can do to export the JAX WS services below a certain path?

**Edit:** The above services are deployed as a webapp, with a DispatcherServlet configured on /*.

Comment: Do you deploy it it a webapp ? If so, can you post your web.xml ? If not, what are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` in your dispatcher servlet configuration, this is required when you have the dispatcher servlet mapped to /*.

Comment: That doesn't change anything as far as I can tell? Still when using SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter I get 404 for all URL's except the exported SOAP webservice.

Answer (score 0):

define separate servlet for web servicess

example from Spring documentation. Note that you will have to define a configuration file for this servlet. http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html se section  5.3.1

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to relate to JAX-WS (which I use). Also I would much prefer a solution with only one spring web context configured.

Comment: try to change the port of ws http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445969/using-jax-ws-webservices-with-spring-3-0-x-on-jboss-as-7-1-x

Comment: But then I would have to run two servers (ports). That seems even worse than multiple application contexts.

Comment: yes it will, but if you use jax-ws it will start another server (provider) by default.I think You  will have to export web services with the JAX-WS RI's Spring support