# Injecting a bean with @Autowired not working in Soap Handler Issue?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, autowired, soaphandler

Hi I have a SOAP Handler class which is handling the logging for request which we get for a Webservice API. I am trying to insert this request in DB inside SOAP Handler. I have created DAOs which i m trying to inject through @Autowired annotation which are used to insert request in DB. But it is giving me Null Pointer Exception instead. Why does @Autowired not work here while it works perfectly well my @Service classes.

Answer (score 0):

Was your SOAP Handler been instanciated by Spring ?
Your `@Service` classes are read and instanciated by Spring at DI Container initialization, so the `@Autowired` can work.

So your handler need to be instancied by Spring to be managed (with a `@Component`-like annotation, for example). If it need to be instanciated by a Java EE container, you should consider extending [SpringBeanAutowiringSupport](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.html)

Regards

Comment: Well i tried the approach you mentioned. still the null pointer exception is persisting. tried with both extending SpringBeanAutowiringSupport as well as adding @Service annotation to the SoapHandler.

Comment: Is your class in the scope of your <component-scan> context configuration ?
You may want to give a look at the question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943082/jax-ws-spring-and-springbeanautowiringsupport

Comment: yes my class is in the <component-scan> context configuration.

Comment: this issue was solved by including SoapHandler class bean by usage of @Autowired annotation in Webservice Impl class.